# proxy cant implement java.lang.Thread

Tags: java, clojure

im trying to implement this in java

```
window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowDestroyNotify(WindowEvent arg0){
                new Thread(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        animator.stop();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }.start();
            };
        });
```

as this in clojure

```
 (.addWindowListener (proxy [WindowAdapter][]
                         (windowDestroyNotify [arg0]
                           (.start (proxy [java.lang.Thread][]
                                     (run
                                       (.stop ani)
                                       (System/exit 0)))))))
```

but when i run it, it gives me this error

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol, compiling:     (program/core.clj:36:36)
```

36:36 is where "(proxy [java.lang.Thread]" starts

why can't it implement java.lang.Thread

Answer (score 2):

The exception is misleading, but the problem is in the implementation of the `run` method in the proxy `Thread`, it is missing the arguments vector.

The following expression when compiled generates the same exception:

```
(proxy [Thread] [] (run (inc 1)))
```

While this one doesn't:

```
(proxy [Thread] [] (run [] (inc 1)))
```

The misleading error is because of how the `proxy` macro parses its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Start over and build it up slowly from small pieces:

```
(let [t (Thread. #(println "going 1")) ]
  (.start t))

;=> going 1

(let [t (proxy [Thread] []
          (run [] (println "going 2")))
]
  (.start t))

;=> going 2
```

So you can see the problem is not `proxy` or `Thread` but in your surrounding code.

### Update

Juan noticed the problem first as the missing arglist `[]` for `run`. By reading the docs at https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/proxy  and building up the sample slowely, I got the arglist in the sample code automatically.

I have found that understanding a problem by "synthesis" allows you to bypass many problems. It is often much faster & easier than trying to understand a problem by "analysis", where you start with the finished product and then try to figure out what caused it to go wrong.